# getting empty output when run the php script in terminal

Tags: php, shell, rest, cron, sh

the following code is working fine in netbeans but not in terminal using shell script.if any one have any idea please share it.

**test3cron.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

@ob_start();
session_start();
$callbackUrl = "http://mgstore/test3cron.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://mgstore/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://mgstore/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://mgstore/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://mgstore/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'd9a371ca7661bee18de8d75f50b7e386';
$consumerSecret = '51486d1b2bd688a927a3eced64ed803e';
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();
    $oauthClient->disableSSLChecks();


    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);

        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {

        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);

        exit;

    } else {

        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = $apiUrl . "/customers?page=400&limit=1";
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, array(), 'GET', array("Content-Type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "*/*"));
        $customerList = json_decode($oauthClient->getLastResponse());

    }
    if (is_array($customerList) || is_object($customerList)) {
        foreach ($customerList as $object) {
            $entityid = $object->entity_id;
            echo "ENTITY ID:" . "$entityid" . "<br>";

            $name1 = $object->firstname;
            $name2 = $object->lastname;
            $customersince = $object->created_at;
            echo "Created at:$customersince<br>";
            $name = $name1 . " " . $name2;
            echo "NAME:" . "$name" . "<br>";
            $email = $object->email;
            echo "EMAIL:" . "$email" . "<br>";
        }
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

when i run the above script in netbeans(shift+f6),i get the following output:

```
ENTITY ID:167
Created at:2015-07-31 12:37:04
NAME:shahid md
EMAIL:shahid@gmail.com
```

the same script,am try to run in terminal as follows,but it shows empty output.

**cron.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPTPATH=$( cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd -P )
PHP='/usr/bin/php'
# tailf /var/log/cron

cd $SCRIPTPATH
# TO RUN ALL CORN JOBS

$PHP -q test3cron.php
```

the following command am using for run the script file:
but am not getting anything here.

> ```
> rizwan@rizwan-Inspiron-3520:~/PHP-workspace/mgstore$ ./cron.sh
>
> rizwan@rizwan-Inspiron-3520:~/PHP-workspace/mgstore$
> ```

and i tried the following link also:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75414/running-the-magento-rest-api-php-example

```
  rizwan@rizwan-Inspiron-3520:~/PHP-workspace/mgstore$ php -S
 localhost:8088 test3cron.php

**Response as follows:**

 PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11 Development Server started at Tue Aug 11
 10:32:54 2015 Listening on http://localhost:8088 Document root is
 /home/rizwan/PHP-workspace/mgstore Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Answer (score 0):

You've enabled Output Buffering via `@ob_start();`, but you never end the output buffering (`ob_end_flush();`). Additionally, setting `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);` is disabling reporting of `NOTICE` errors (just set it to `-1`).

You're also accessing `$_SESSION` from a CLI script. This can be made to work, but it might not be doing what you expect.

But, it seems to me that what's actually going on here, is that you're simply entering an execution path that doesn't produce any output. See here:

```
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);

        exit;
```

As this is not an HTTP request, `$_GET['oauth_token']` will not be set, and, `$_SESSION['state']` will be `0` and thus falsey. All it does is get a token, output a header, and exit the script. I bet if you put an `echo` in that branch of your code, you'd see it print. My recommended course of action for debugging is to add `echo` statements throughout and trace the execution path of the code.

Comment: thank u very much for u r response,am new to php,can you explain clearly,the code is executing only if block,if i give any echo after if block it wont works.

Comment: please,Can anyone give any idea for this ?